# Add gift card to cart

Tags: cart

How can I programatically add Gift Card with message to cart ? I was able to add configurable and simple products; but not gif cards.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the product id for the gift card?

Comment: Yes I have the product id with me; but, I don't know how to pass email address and custom message.

Comment: Is the message always customized or is it a general gift card message?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, by adding gift cart attributes to the addtocart method.

```
$quote          =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); /* Current Quote Object */
$productId      = 34; /* Product ID*/
$params         = array();
$curQuantity    = 3; /* Item Quantity */
$currentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);  
$params['product']                  = $productId;
$params['qty']                      = $curQuantity;               
$params['giftcard_amount']          = 200; /* Gift Card Amount */
$params['giftcard_sender_name']     = 'My Name'; /* Sender Name */
$params['giftcard_recipient_name']  = 'test@gmail.com'; /* Sender Email */
$params['giftcard_sender_email']    = 'Your Name'; /* Recipient Name */
$params['giftcard_recipient_email'] = 'test2@gmail.com'; /* Recipient Email */  
$request                            = new Varien_Object(); 
$request->setData($params);
$resultItem = $quote->addProduct($currentProduct , $request);
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you think it best answers your question.